# Ignore Shared Navbar rails 3

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3

i am using rails for my current project and am making a landing page for IE5-7 users stating we are not currently supporting for now. ( will be working on getting this done).

I am using a _shared Navabr for all my pages but obviously want to hide this for the landing IE landing page only. Is there a way to ignore this for just the one page, either CSS or javascript. I’ve tried playing with the css to display:none for the navbar ( its twitter bootstrap) but no joy as yet

Is there anything I can do in the controller using the render option?

Anyone come across this before

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one. thought I would share it

It layouts/application place this above the header

```
 <% unless current_page?(:controller => 'public_pages', :action => 'internetex7')  %>
```

then place

```
   <% end %>
```

just before the

```
    </ul>
```